# Level of education required for employment over time

Tags: education, demographics

I want to get a data set that can be used to look at a year and the levels of education required for employment.

My thoughts are that although we have many more opportunities in the modern world the level of education required to access these opportunities is increasing. I would like a dataset that helps answer that question

Note I suspect the change in education required would have started to occur around the late 70s so a data set at least from 1930 would be useful

Comment: my experience in web development says exactly the opposite: best devs and hackers didn't go to school/dropped out. and they have the best employment options available at the moment.

Comment: there are many businesses that require computer science or some sort of bachelor degree just to be considered. businesses are willing to forgo that requirement because they need developers more than college graduates. It's a worthwhile question. seems like the job sites would have this data

Comment: this may have what op is seeking: http://census.gov/data/tables/time-series/demo/income-poverty/cps-pinc/pinc-04.html

Comment: @albert it looks like it, i could take average earnings by age group at a certain year and used that, just would like one that goes back even further

Comment: it goes back to 1994. how long do you want it? also, add that requirement to your request

Comment: no problem. that is a big dataset you seek. i hope you/we find it!

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at the [US Occupational Employment Statistics historical data](https://www.bls.gov/oes/tables.htm).

That data allowed for the creation of this chart: [image: Employment by typical entry-level educational requirement, as a percentage oftotal employment, May 2016]

The original chart is available as a [BLS publication](https://www.bls.gov/opub/ted/2017/37-percent-of-may-2016-employment-in-occupations-typically-requiring-postsecondary-education.htm).

Unfortunately this doesn’t go as far back as you would like.